# Why Gradle is compiling .java files but not creating my .jar?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, compilation

I recently started using Gradle but i'm having an issue compiling my application.

This is my build.gradle:

```
group 'net.zentya'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    compile 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.11.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.bukkit:bukkit:1.11.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'net.md-5:bungeecord-chat:1.11-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

When building with the IntelliJ's pre-made button i get my project compiled's class files into the path {project}/gradle/classes/main . But i don't have the final JAR. 
How i can fix?

Comment: Invoke `gradle jar`, or `gradle assemble`. Why don't you read the gradle guide? That's what it's for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gradle jar or gradle shadowJar commands can be used to create the jar file of gradle based applications.

Comment: shadowJar is not a standard task of the java or groovy plugin.

Comment: The jar task made it. Thank you!